# Composer update : Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, composer-php

I updated my server with PHP 7.4.2 and now I am getting this :

```
~/public_html/infusionsoft$ php composer.phar update


  [ErrorException]                                    
  Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

I had to revert back to 7.3.14 and it works. But is composer not PHP 7.4 ready ?

Comment: Can you share more details? Which version of Composer do you use? What's the configuration of your `composer.json`?

Comment: I didn't check what version of composer I was using before. I re-download composer and it's now working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a composer issue and has been fixed in this release: `https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/8296`

In order to fix this issue please update your composer.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to update composer itself, I get the same error :-)

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue after upgrading from PHP 7.2 to 7.4. The self-update had the same error.

I resolved it by re-installing composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then use composer.phar, or move it to where you have composer installed (for me, `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`).